# Connecting points with Z values to lines where the Z values are retained in the nodes of the resulting line

Tags: qgis, line, 3d, algorithm, xyz

I have interpreted seismic data as xyz-points (about 23 cm lateral resolution). They are not really ordered but rather a simple list of coordinates. One file contains multiple seismic "lines".

I have a 3D-modelling software that can show lines in 3D if the nodes have z-values. However, the software itself does not have the function to combine these points into lines but rather triangulate them into 3D-Meshes. While this is useful, it doesn't look very good or is representative of the actual geology that the xyz-point represent.

In QGIS I have found the function to connect points (points to path) to lines but since there are 4 "lines" next to each other as seen in the screenshot:
[image: 4 seismic "lines" made up of xyz-points from one file. What may look like lines already are thousands of dots with a distance of 0.23 cm between each other.]
*Fig.1: 4 seismic "lines" made up of xyz-points from one file. What may look like lines already are thousands of dots with a distance of 0.23 cm between each other.*

and sometimes these lines are interrupted because the corresponding seismic horizon is non-existent in that area. So even if I would use the "path to lines" function, I do not have any column to order the connections by. I cannot use either the x- or "better the y-coordinates (as the lines run roughly from north to south) because the lines will be interconnected this way.

I need an algorithm that can "recognize" each line and connect the points but interrupts the line building process when the distance between the points is greater than the lateral resolution and restarts with the next point after the break. So one line for each coloured arrow in the following screenshot.
[image]

Oh and we cannot forget that the resulting lines should contain the 3D data, meaning each node/point should retain its z-value.